# A twitter api either not connecting on node or some other issue

Tags: node.js, express, window

```
sony@Tesla MINGW64 ~/Downloads/Twitter API JavaScript Node Exercise/1. Introduction to Connecting to Twitter API/tweet
$ npm start

> tweet@1.0.0 start
> node index.js

**RESTART**
node
node:_http_outgoing:576
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\sony\Downloads\Twitter API JavaScript Node Exercise\1. Introduction to Connecting to Twitter API\tweet\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\sony\Downloads\Twitter API JavaScript Node Exercise\1. Introduction to Connecting to Twitter API\tweet\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:264:10)
    at C:\Users\sony\Downloads\Twitter API JavaScript Node Exercise\1. Introduction to Connecting to Twitter API\tweet\index.js:29:11
    at C:\Users\sony\Downloads\Twitter API JavaScript Node Exercise\1. Introduction to Connecting to Twitter API\tweet\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:127:13
    at onRequestComplete (C:\Users\sony\Downloads\Twitter API JavaScript Node Exercise\1. Introduction to Connecting to Twitter API\tweet\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:347:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sony\Downloads\Twitter API JavaScript Node Exercise\1. Introduction to Connecting to Twitter API\tweet\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:364:7)
    at Request.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sony\Downloads\Twitter API JavaScript Node Exercise\1. Introduction to Connecting to Twitter API\tweet\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28)
    at Gunzip.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

Issue: My localhost also shuts down because of the above-mentioned error. Nodemon is also installed on my node server, and I am on window 10. Is there any credential validation issue in the API?

Issue: My localhost also shuts down because of the above-mentioned error. Nodemon is also installed on my node server, and I am on window 10. Is there any credential validation issue in the API?

What steps should I take to troubleshoot?

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
// const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Twit = require('twit')
 
const T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         'XXXXXXXXXX',
  consumer_secret:      'XXXXXXXXXX',
  access_token:         'XXXXXXXXXX-fQAQuerobj4eoRRoOx3V49t6uKU8HOn',
  access_token_secret:  'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  timeout_ms:           60*1000,
  strictSSL:            true,
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencode({extended:false}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(express.json());


app.get('/tweets/:search', function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.params.search);
  res.json({'status':'Success'})
  T.get('search/tweets', 
    { q: req.params.search, 
      count: 7 }, function(err, data, response) {
      res.json(data)
  })
})


app.listen(3000);
console.log("**RESTART**");
```

Comment: Remove this line `res.json({'status':'Success'})`

Comment: Ok, the semicolon was an issue?

Comment: No, just call `res.json` once.

Comment: Can you help me to understand the reason when you said that → "No, just call res.json once."

Comment: You call res.json twice, in the second time it will throw `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error.

Comment: Ok, Can you write this as a solution?